# PHP. working with list() and each()?

Tags: php, list, each

This is a working example code from php doc for using list() with each()

```
<?php

$fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');

reset($fruit);
while (list($key, $val) = each($fruit)) {
    echo "$key => $val\n";
}
?>
```

The output is

```
a => apple
b => banana
c => cranberry
```

I don't understand why it works and output that way. Because,

from the [API of each()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php), it says each() return an array with **4** key/value pair.
So `each($fruit)` should be like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => yy
    [value] => yy
    [0] => xx
    [key] => xx
)
```

for the code:

```
while (list($key, $val) = each($fruit)) {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
```

shouldn't `$key` equal to `each($fruit)[1]`,  and `$val` equal to `each($fruit)[value]`?

Comment: `foreach` is the tool of your choice!

Comment: With foreach, PHP iterates over a copy of the array instead of the actual array. In contrast, when using each( ) and for, PHP iterates over the original array.

Comment: nothing wrong, just different choices. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note:
>
> `list()` only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.
>
> http://php.net/list

In other words, `list` actively looks for numerical keys in order. `list($foo, $bar)` requires that the assigned array has the keys `0` and `1` and will assign those to `$foo` and `$bar` respectively. It doesn't matter which order these keys are in in the array itself.

Comment: great catch. appreciate that.

Comment: Note: This may have changed in PHP 7

Answer (score 1):

Things are updated in PHP 7.1

What's new?

- list() has a new shorthand
- list() supports named keys

## list()'s shorthand

```php
$array = [3,5,1];
[$a, $b, $c] = $array;
```

## Using for named keys

```php
$fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');
['a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c] = $fruit;

// $a = 'apple'
// $b = 'banana';
// $c = 'cranberry';
```

Source: [PHP list()](https://developer.hyvor.com/php-list)